# Where is CV_USRTYPE1 depth param on Python dir(cv2)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

I can't find `CV_USRTYPE1` on Python, however, It is possible to enum all other depths with `dir(cv2)`.

The following code:

```
import cv2
import re


depths = [i for i in dir(cv2) if re.search('^CV_(?:\d+[A-Z]{1}|USRTYPE1)$', i, re.IGNORECASE)]
print(depths)
```

Returns:

```
['CV_16S', 'CV_16U', 'CV_32F', 'CV_32S', 'CV_64F', 'CV_8S', 'CV_8U']
```

**Where is `CV_USRTYPE1`? Or is there another way to get the `depths`?**

Is it something related to [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commit/6d7f5871dbf9e1e9082c6a99f5358e413e844b80)? That CV_16F was added and [CV_USRTYPE1](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/traits.hpp) is legacy?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve that you need to use `CV_USRTYPE1` in Python? I highly suspect that it's not available in Python, since it's only useful when working with the C++ API.

Comment: Nothing, just reading about `depth`, `type` and `ddepth`. I read about `CV_USRTYPE1` and was curious to try. But wasn't finding it to test. But it is going to be obsolete on 4.0.0 either way

Comment: Then I wouldn't worry about it. It's extremely rarely used, and as you found, will be gone in the next major version anyway. Also, in Python you don't really have `cv::Mat` where this would apply -- numpy arrays are used instead.